# Permutation question (Known answer, don't understand how to get to it)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

To save your time, I simplify the question to something like this:

> There are $18$ people, $4$ of which are teachers. All of them($18$) are going to stand in a row. In how many ways can they be arranged such that no teachers stand next to each other?

And the answer for this question is around $2.32\times10^{10}$. I have no idea how to get to the answer. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have $14$ ordinary people and $4$ teachers, and told to arrange in such a way, that no teacher stand together. First place the ordinary $14$ people. So, there are $15$ places to allocate the teachers. The diagram below illustrates this.
$$-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-|-,$$ where $|$ denote the $14$ ordinary people, and $-$ denote the spaces between them. This can be done in $14!$ ways.

Now, if you place the $4$ teachers in any of these $15$ places. they can never be adjacent. So, the answer should be $$14!\times\binom {15}4,$$ and also, if the order of those teachers is relevant, then, the answer should be $$14!\times4!\times\binom{15}4.$$

Comment: Yeah I used a similar approach, however, I could not get to the answer...

Comment: Guess the answer might be wrong then...